# Populating MudTreeView from JSON data received via external API

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
I'm new to Blazor and MudBlazor. I have a current requirement that requires a treeview menu.

Several calls to an external API return JSON Data.
The 1st call returns the Hub - this is the root of the treemenu.
The 2nd call returns the Projects within the hub.
The 3rd call returns the Folders within the project.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here, How do I use the MudTreeView component to build this menu? This menu will sit inside it's own component and not to be confused with the existing NavMenu.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a class that describe each nodes of your TreeView. I've created one for another TreeView, with another library but the logic is the same.

```
public class TreeItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? ParentIdValue { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; } = string.Empty; //maybe useless for you
    public TypeOfItemEnum TypeOfItem { get; set; }
    public Guid? RelatifId { get; set; } //maybe useless for you
}
```

Here, `TypeOfItemEnum` helps me to know from which API the result came from (if it is a "file", a "folder" or a "project" as you mentioned).

Then you will transform each result of your first API into a collection of this TreeItemModel. Then you append to this list the results of your second call API (transformed into a collection of TreeItemMode), then your third results etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Blazor component which will convert any piece of JSON into a **MudTreeView** using `System.Text.Json`.  The first component is the tree itself, and the second component helps to recursively build out the tree.  You can also set optional properties `Hover`, `Dense`, and `Sorted`.  The tree nodes will display a MudIcon based on the data type of each node: date, GUID, number, boolean, or string.

### Usage

Once components are added to your project, simply set the `Json` property to any valid JSON text.

*[Example.razor]*

```
<JsonTreeView Json="@Json" Dense="true" Hover="true" Sorted="true" />
```

*[Example.razor.cs]*

```
public string Json { get; set; }

public async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Json = await api.GetSomeJsonAsync();
}
```

### Code

Add these Razor components and code-behind files to your project.

*[JsonTreeView.razor]*

```
<MudTreeView T="string" Dense="@Dense" Hover="@Hover">
    <JsonTreeViewNode Node="Root" Sorted="@Sorted" />
</MudTreeView>
```

*[JsonTreeView.razor.cs]*

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a tree view which displays a snippet of JSON.
/// </summary>
public partial class JsonTreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the JSON to be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string Json { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the root node of the JSON to display.
    /// </summary>
    public JsonNode Root { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the tree contents are compacted.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public bool Dense { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the current row is highlighted.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public bool Hover { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether items are sorted by key.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public bool Sorted { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Root = JsonNode.Parse(Json);
    }
}
```

*[JsonTreeViewNode.razor]*

```
@using System.Text.Json;

@if (Node is JsonObject)
{
    @* Is sorting is enabled, sort by key *@
    var nodes = Sorted ? Node.AsObject().OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value) : Node.AsObject().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    @* Go through each item *@
    foreach (var child in nodes)
    {
        if (child.Value is JsonValue)
        {
            @* Get the type of value in this node *@
            var valueKind = child.Value.AsValue().GetValue<JsonElement>().ValueKind;
            switch (valueKind)
            {
                case JsonValueKind.String:
                    var str = child.Value.AsValue().GetValue<string>();
                    @* Could be a date *@
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out DateTime date))
                    {
                        <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DateRange" EndText="@date.ToString()"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    }
                    @* Could be a GUID *@
                    else if (Guid.TryParse(str, out Guid guid))
                    {
                        <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Key" EndText="@str.ToUpperInvariant()"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    }
                    @* Fall back to string *@
                    else
                    {
                        <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.TextSnippet" EndText="@str"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    }
                    break;
                case JsonValueKind.Number:
                    var number = child.Value.AsValue().GetValue<int>();
                    <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Numbers" EndText="@number.ToString()"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    break;
                case JsonValueKind.True:
                    <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CheckBox" EndText="true"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    break;
                case JsonValueKind.False:
                    <MudTreeViewItem T="string" Text="@child.Key" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CheckBoxOutlineBlank" EndText="false"></MudTreeViewItem>
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (child.Value is JsonArray)
        {
            <MudTreeViewItem T="string" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Folder" Text="@child.Key" EndTextClass="mud-primary-text" EndText="(Array)">
                @* Iterate each array element *@
                <JsonTreeViewNode Node="@child.Value" Sorted="@Sorted" />
            </MudTreeViewItem>
        }
    }
}
else if (Node is JsonArray)
{
    var count = 0;
    @* Iterate each array element *@
    foreach (var child in Node.AsArray())
    {
        count++;
        <MudTreeViewItem T="string" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Folder" EndTextClass="mud-primary-text" EndText="@($"(Item {count})")">
            <JsonTreeViewNode Node="@child" Sorted="@Sorted" />
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    }
}
```

*[JsonTreeViewNode.razor.cs]*

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the child leaf of a JSON tree view.
/// </summary>
public partial class JsonTreeViewNode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the node to display (including children).
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public JsonNode Node { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether items are sorted by key.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public bool Sorted { get; set; }
}
```